# define setting only if a condition is met

Tags: scala, sbt

Question regarding conditional settings. I'm trying to have a setting defined only if a certain condition is met:

`lazy val proj = project
  .settings(/*other settings...*/)
  .settings((if (condition) Seq(foo := bar.value) else Seq.empty): _*)`

Except, my code would really look more legible if I could do this on individual setting basis, e.g.:

`project.settings(
  // other settings...
  if (condition) (foo := bar.value) else (hole := Nil) 
  // other settings...
)`

Is there any neat and accepted way of accomplishing this? what would be a good candidate for a "monoidal zero" setting?

Comment: Why not just use `settingKey[Option[Whatever]]`?

Comment: With a ```Setting[Option[_]]``` I end up assigning either ```Some(...)``` or ```None```. When the condition evaluates to false, I want to avoid assignment completely.

Comment: Just curious, if you want to access the setting that is (conditionally) not defined, which value do you expect it to have?

Comment: If I avoid assigning to a key, I'd expect it to have whatever value it was assigned beforehand. Come to think about it, that sounds a bit like ```~=```.

Comment: Ah ok, you mean changing setting's value, not defining a new setting. Then your question has to be rephrased accordingly, I think.

Comment: I mean assigning/altering a value if a condition is met, doing nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.configure`

```
val prj = project.settings(...).configure { p =>
  if (foo) {
    p.settings(...)
  } else p
}
```

Comment: trying to have this incorporated inside a single settings sequence